# How legal is this definition of `main`?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, program-entry-point

In a hosted system, the standard requires `main` be defined with a "declared return type of type `int`". The "declared" here appertains to "deduced return types" so we can ignore that word for the purposes of this question. In C, the standard explicitly has a footnote that says a `typedef` can be used for `int` but this is missing in the C++ standard. I'm going to assume the intent is the same as the language is "return type of type `int`" and  "a function of () returning `int`" and a `typedef` is simply an alias, not a different type. Therefore this program would be considered legal:

```
typedef int boobs;
boobs main() { }
```

What if we do this instead?

```
#include <cstdint>

int32_t main() {}
```

On many systems this will compile as `int32_t` is just `int` but not all systems. My confusion stems from the fact that `int32_t` is an implementation-defined value, meaning compilation failure depends on the implementation.

So what's the legality of this situation? Is the entire program ill-formed because it can sometimes compile or not? Or is it well-formed because it depends on an implementation-defined value that comes from the standard library?

Comment: `so we can ignore that word for the ` - leave me out of this

Comment: what would be the use of this? I mean if it works only in case `int32_t` is just `int` then you could as well use `int` in first place

Comment: "compilation failure depends on the implementation"---yes, that can happen, it's nothing unusual

Comment: @tobi303 No practical usage, purely pedagogical.

Comment: You might as well have asked if it's okay that `#ifdef __VENDOR__` / `#error I hate (vendor)` / `#endif` compiles with non-(vendor) compilers. If there would be any wording in the standard that required it to be an error on all implementations, then that would surely be a defect in the standard. That said, that doesn't answer the question: such a defect could in theory exist.

Comment: @hvd I think my situation is pretty narrowly tailored. Both definition of `main` and `int32_t` are clearly defined by the standard so the vendor can't do anything in that regard without being non-conforming.

Comment: After re-reading your post: the question of whether this is ill-formed/well-formed can be read two ways, and I read it one particular way, which may not be what you intended. Are you asking whether implementations may/must diagnose this, or are you asking what the proper term is for conditionally-erroneous code?

Comment: @hvd Neither I think. It's already pretty clear that `non-int-type main()` should not compile, period. I also don't think this case is conditional compilation. You could arguably compile this with a broken standard library that gives a non-conforming value of `int32_t`, but assuming a conforming standard library that gives a valid value for `int32_t` that fails compilation, is the overall program "legal"?

Comment: In other words I find the concept that fail to compile on a certain implementation affects the legality of the program.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question, multiple times.  As far as I can see, the only hangup is that you're amazed that some compilers on some platforms might reject a program that other compilers accept on different platforms.

Answer (score 4):

The program is well formed if and only if `int32_t` is an alias (a typedef) of `int`.

Obviously, in systems that do not support `int32_t` (fixed width integers are optional), the use of non-declared `int32_t` is illegal.

Also, even if `int32_t` is supported by the compiler, it is not required to declare it in the global namespace in the header `<cstdint>` (only `std::int32_t` is guaranteed), so the program relies on that aspect of the implementation.

Also, in systems where `int32_t` is another type distinct from `int`, the program will be ill formed.

So, it is implementantion defined, whether the program is well formed or not. On some systems it is; on others it's not. To put it even more concisely, the program is conditionally well formed.